# I have IP conflicts and I can't host my server anymore

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip, ipv6

My father and I have the same IP address on my network. (I found this on cmyip.com)
This makes it impossible for me to host servers (for instance minecraft or terraria) and I don't know the solution.
Everyone I've asked so far says "Set a manual IP" but nothing I've found shows me how.

Anyone got any help? I kind of desperate after a year and a half of this...

Comment: You have the same public IP, but different internal IPs. You need to configure your router to forward specific game ports to specific computers on the internal network in order to host game servers. If you have IPv6 available, then this is not an issue, but there are very few providers (especially in the US) which are providing IPv6 connectivity to residential users at this point in time.

Comment: You can forward specific ports to specific internal intranet addresses.  The exact process depends on your router.  For instructions check the online documentation for your router.

Comment: Depending on what wireless router you have, It is not impossible for you to host servers. Please research the basics of home networking. Google: `How home networks work` and stumble upon http://www.howstuffworks.com/home-network.htm

Answer (score 4):

Like all the comments above suggest you need to forward the correct ports from the outside to your own computer within your local network. There is a website which has a large database of routers and games where you can look up exactly how to forward the correct port(s) for your router:

[Portforward.com](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/routerindex.htm)

The games minecraft and terraria are both included in the guides (alongside hundreds of others).